Unable to load class named DefaultDynamicJwkBuilder from the thread context
I am trying to generate a JWK from jjwt-api with the below code. It is just a simple snippet with RSA 256 (2048 bits)

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
    import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Jwks;
    import io.jsonwebtoken.security.RsaPrivateJwk;
    
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
    
    public class Test {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     RsaPrivateJwk privJwk = Jwks.builder()
      .id("test-key-id")
      .key((RSAPrivateKey) Jwts.SIG.RS256.keyPair().build().getPrivate()) //2048 bits
      .build();
     String jwkJson = new String(new Gson().toJson(privJwk).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     System.out.println(jwkJson);
     }
    
    }


This is my pom

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
     <groupId>org.example</groupId>
     <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
     <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>
    
     <dependencies>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
     <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
     <version>0.12.6</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
     <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
     <version>0.12.6</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
     <artifactId>jjwt-gson</artifactId>
     <version>0.12.6</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.0</version>
     </dependency>
     </dependencies>
    
    </project>


I am getting the below exception in spite of having jjwt-impl as a runtime dependency. I did try several things such as cleaning and reimporting the project but that doesn't seem to work.
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.12-oracle-x64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57679,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/home/abhi/Downloads/idea-IC-242.20224.387/plugins/java/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug.enable.creation.stack.trace=false -Ddebugger.agent.enable.coroutines=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/abhi/Projects/lib-service-java/target/classes:/home/abhi/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api/0.12.6/jjwt-api-0.12.6.jar:/home/abhi/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.0/gson-2.9.0.jar:/home/abhi/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.9.0/commons-cli-1.9.0.jar:/home/abhi/Downloads/idea-IC-242.20224.387/lib/idea_rt.jar Test
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57679', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" io.jsonwebtoken.lang.UnknownClassException: Unable to load class named [io.jsonwebtoken.impl.security.DefaultDynamicJwkBuilder] from the thread context, current, or system/application ClassLoaders.  All heuristics have been exhausted.  Class could not be found.  Have you remembered to include the jjwt-impl.jar in your runtime classpath?
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.forName(Classes.java:90)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:173)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.security.Jwks.builder(Jwks.java:56)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57679', transport: 'socket'
Process finished with exit code 1


Do you have a module-info.java file in your project? How exactly are you running the application?

I don't have a module-info.java file, is that required?

I'm running it from IntelliJ through the main method

No, it isn't required but I could imagine using modules causing some issues like that.

@dan1st any idea about the error or workarounds?

I don't know but you could try running it with mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=Test (you can enter this after pressing Ctrl twice in IntelliJ I think) to see whether this still happens when executing it with Maven, remove <scope>runtime</scope> (though that shouldn't cause the issue) or update/reload the Maven project in IntelliJ.
